# Copy files with wild card and add timestamp

Tags: shell

I have to copy a file `Test_*.txt` to `Test_20190101_Timestamp.txt`, where `*` is a wild card and `20190101` is the date.

```
cp test_*.txt test_*_"$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)".txt
```

When I copy the files the output copy is also coming as `Test_*_Timestamp.txt`. How can I copy the entire file without the wildcards?

I've also tried this, but it also failed

```
cp test_*.txt test*_"$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)".txt 
cp: target 'test*_20200102-160523.txt' is not a directory
```

Comment: do you mean it is a list of files or a unique file with "*" char in its name ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Can you give us the exact command you're using to copy the file?

Comment: cp test_*.txt test_*_"$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)".txt

Comment: Francois:  I have one file, but i have to automate it through ETL tool for which i have to use cp command in the tool. When i copy the file with the wildcard, the wild card the output is also coming with * but not the actual file name

Comment: cp test_*.txt test_*_"$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)".txt
cp: target ‘test_*_20200102-160523.txt’ is not a directory

Comment: I've copied your comments back into the question, so they can be more easily seen by people wanting to help. Please double-check that I've interpreted your commands correctly, as it is essential the text is correct. (If it's not, please [edit] it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the files:

```bsh
for file in Test_*.txt; do
    fileroot=${file%.txt}    # remove the extension
    cp -v "$file" "${fileroot}_Timestamp.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem - as you may have found out - is that you assumed in your original attempt that the actual value of the wildcard is "transferred" between the different arguments of your command (i.e. from your source filename to your intended target filename).

However, this is not how wildcard expansion (or, rather, "glob expansion") works in the shell. Rather, everywhere a wildcard appears, the shell expands this internally to a list of matching files and executes your command as if you had specified the entire list (see e.g. [this tutorial](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) on shell globbing). So, if you have files

```
Test_a.txt
Test_b.txt
Test_c.txt
```

in your directory, your `cp` command would actually behave as if you had typed

```
cp Test_a.txt Test_b.txt Test_c.txt Test_*_20200102-160523.txt
```

Since the last argument is taken as the destination of the copy command, and you have specified multiple source files, `cp` assumes this to be a directory and complains that no directory of that name exists.

Why now does it complain about there being no `Test_*_20200102-160523.txt` directory with *a literal* `*` in it? The standard behaviour (at least of the `bash`) is that if you specify a wildcard character and there is no matching file present, the wildcard character will be interpreted literally as itself - and since your expression `Test_*_20200102-160523.txt` was intended as target filename, it does not yet exist in the current directory.

This is the reason behind @glennjackman's answer that you need to loop over your input files to achieve the desired result.