# Move wild card files adding timestamp

Tags: bash, shell-script

Requirement is to move the files from source to archive folder adding timestamp
I have created the below script but it is not moving the date which i am passing as wild card

```
File name: Test_20100101.txt
```

```
sourcedir=/projects/source
archivedir=/projects/archive
FILE="$1"

for file in $1; do
    fileroot=$1
  mv -i "$sourcedir/$1"* "$archivedir/$1_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")"
done
```

while executing i am running the script as below

```
./archfiles.sh Test_
```

but the output is coming as

```
Test__20200107_092902
```

the actual output should be

```
Test_20100101_20200107_092902.txt
```

can you please help me on this

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560010/copy-files-with-wild-card-and-add-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use a `for` loop when you don't use the loop variable `file`. If you want to process the files from a wildcard expansion one by one you have to use the wildcard in the `for` statement, not in the loop body.

(It looks as if you modified the code from the related question [Copy files with wild card and add timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560010/copy-files-with-wild-card-and-add-timestamp) without understanding it.)

If the files are located in a different directory `$sourcedir` you have to either (1) specify `$sourcedir` together with the wildcard or (2) change the current directory to `$sourcedir`.

Example 1:

```
for file in "$sourcedir/$1"*
do
    base="${file##*/}"
    mv -i "$sourcedir/$base" "$archivedir/${base}_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")"
done
```

Example 2 (assuming `sourcedir` and `archivedir` are absolute paths):

```
cd "$sourcedir"
for file in "$1"*
do
    mv -i "$file" "$archivedir/${file}_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")"
done
```

(All code is untested.)